# How to find which crawled/managed property belongs to which column of a list?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I know crawling in SharePoint automatically creates crawled properties for us. We can use them to create managed properties.

Is there any configuration or setting from which we come to know that which crawled/managed property belongs to which column of a list? or is there any other way to know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the rule of 'naming convention for automatically created crawled and managed properties' section.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794220.aspx